# Переписать или отлаживать дальше?

Tags: best-practice

Написал прогу, тестовое задание для приема на работу. Код вышел крайне кривой.
Т.е. он-то работает, но малейшая ошибка (при изменении исходных данных или еще что-либо) разбивает его вдребезги.

Вот собственно хочу спросить совета у бывалых, что лучше делать в таких случаях: пытаться дописать, довести до ума получившееся *"УГ"* или все-таки лучше взять и переписать все на чистовик, абы сверкало и не глючило?

Просто я так подумал, если я так все время буду делать, это ж сколько времени уйдет даром, если так вот код переписывать всякий раз, когда мне в нем что-то не нравится.

Comment: Конечно же переписать. Если жалко времени на перфекционизм, то профессия программиста вам не подходит.

Comment: Я просто сам не до конца понимаю как лучше сделать те или иные штуки. Вариантов много как бы а какой из них лучше непонятно.

Comment: Дык по мере оттачивания навыка у вас еще не раз возникнет желание переписать :-) В это и заключается стремление к совершенству.

Comment: - Тестовое задание, в принципе, можно, поскольку его черновую реализацию вы можете расценивать как `"experiment branch"`. Но сама по себе идеология *переписывания* какого-либо работающего продукта в реальной жизни не выдерживает конкуренции.

- Для улучшения кода придуман **рефакторинг.** Рекомендую, кстати говоря, попробовать сначала покрыть свой код тестами и отрефакторить его, нежели вслепую бросаться все переписывать, хотя, как я уже сказал, для тестового задания подход переписывания имеет право на жизнь.

Comment: Котик, прошу Вас, расскажите тогда хотя бы немного поподробней что такое _покрывающие тесты_, где их брать, и как имплементировать в свою программу. Плюс+ многие функции я уже отдебажил (прошелся вручную отладчиком и выявил их слабые и\или кривые места), просто, опять-таки, сам вид получившегося кода меня пугает.

Comment: Просто получился так называемый "быдло код" а мне показывать работодателю что я так пишу ну совсем никак не хочется. и еще. работу с файлами можно ли проводить внутри вызываемой функции. или файл (и ошибки, связанные с его открытием), лучше открывать в *main*, а в тело передавать только дескриптор?

Comment: И насчет ошибок - обработку ошибок лучше осуществлять с помощью блоков **try** и **catch** либо же получать в Main код, что возвращает функция и уже по нем смотреть, что не так?

Comment: @pol500 Извините за оффтоп, а куда вы пытаетесь устроиться на работу *(можно примерный уровень компании или просто назовите похожую компанию)?*

Comment: @pol500

- Насчет исключений есть 2 принципиально разных школы. Лично я предпочитаю `Google C++ Style Guide`, который запрещает их использование в принципе.

- Если вы собираетесь передавать хэндлы на файлы в функцию, то точно *(хотя бы в комментариях к ней)* опишите ее контракт - что она может и что должна делать с этим хэндлом.

Comment: @pol500, Вы программу (ТЗ на нее) хоть в общих чертах опишите. 

А то конкретно-то сказать нечего. Книжки (как советуют правильно писать) Вы наверное сами читали.

Comment: Я вижу только одну проблему: если окажется, что после переписывания Вы потратили очень много времени. Работодатель может сказать "это ты всегда с такой скоростью работать будешь?" Как-то я одно тестовое задание делал часов 12-15 и то, многие вещи оставил на среднем уровне. А мой будущий коллега на то же задание потратил, насколько я помню, 60 часов. Он действительно больший перфекционист, чем я. Взяли обоих

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Думаю, что если вы сами не понимаете как ведет себя ваша же программа, то ее обязательно надо переписать. Тем более, что она - тестовое задание. И не просто переписать, а показать, на что вы способны по-максимуму.

А за время не беспокойтесь - опыт останется при вас, так что вы даже скорее найдете работу при качественном выполнении тестового заданий.

Comment: переписать ее то действительно надо. только сначала разобратся почему она не работает, иначе автор еще раз допустит ту же ошибку. ибудет уже 2 программы которые надо было переписать. рекурсия не находите?

Answer (score 6):

Часто прогеры мечутся между двумя крайностями:

1. Первая крайность: пытаются заведомо нерабочий код сделать рабочим разнообразными примочками, мелкими правками и проч. В итоге код запутывается до невозможности
2. Вторая крайность: перфекционизм - несмотря на то что код рабочий вылизывают код до потери пульса или же подгоняют под какой-нибудь приличный паттерн. Функционал при этом остается прежним, а трудозатраты растут.

Я для себя выработал несколько правил:

- а. Если код работает - то стараюсь не
     вносить мелкие улучшения. Правило:
     "**Не трогай то что работает!**"
- б. Код подлежит замене, если его
     расширение/модификация привносит
     проблемы - это сигнал к пересмотру
     кода (даже если код работает).
     Правило: "**модификации должны быть
     гладкими**"
- в. Если править код, то надо править
     конкретно! Правило: "**лучше 1
     большое изменение, чем 10
     маленьких**"

Исходя из этого я бы определил, что код автора подлежит замене  - согласно правилам а) и б)

Comment: Либо я неправильно понял третий пункт, либо ваш подход очень огорчает Фаулера :)

Comment: Этот ответ также огорчает перфекционистов, [математиков](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB) и педантов. :-)

Comment: Ну значит Фаулер перфекционист, а я нет. Переживу :)

Comment: строго имхо: умозаключения правильные, "правила" не очень. в нашей компании используется негласное правило "меньше изменений = лучше". если грядут гранзиозные изменения то все равно в пределах каждого отдельного класса или метода мы стараемся делать минимум изменений